# basemapでbluemarbleの使用によるエラーについて

Tags: python

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

python3でbluemarbleを使用するとエラーが発生し図が表示されなくなります　使わないと図は表示されます　対処法を教えてください

Comment: 関連issue?： https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7808

Comment: 関連issue?： https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/336

Comment: 両方確認してもよくわかりませんでした　mplライセンスをとるのかapiを変えればいいのか

Comment: mpl2.0で非推奨になった関数をbasemapが使っているために出ているエラーです。上流では修正されてる（上コメントリンクの内容）ので、anacondaを更新してみてはいかがでしょうか。でダメだとanacondaの更新を待つか、別にbasemapだけを更新すれば治ると思います（多分面倒）。

Comment: condaを更新したらエラーはでますが図が表示されるようになりました。ありがとうございます

Comment: 随分と時間が立ってしまってからですが、自分が質問者様のコードをそのまま書き写し実行してみたところ、`OSError`が出ました。`conda -c install conda-forge basemap-data-hires`と打って、`basemap-data-hires`をインストールせよと言われました。そのため、これをインストールすれば、エラーは全く出てきませんでした。私の環境は、`python3.6.3` `windows10`です。しかし、同じエラーではないようなので、コメントにとどめます。